# Как исправить пропущенные при десериализации поля?

Tags: c#, сериализация

Мне нужно написать класс с устойчивой к изменению версии сериализацией. То есть такой, который бы поддерживал схему "сериализовал, добавил новое поле, десериализовал".

Для этого я должен помечать новые поля атрибутом `[OptionalField]`, а метод, в котором буду производить корректировку пропущенных полей атрибутом `[OnDeserializing]`.

- Но как я узнаю, какое из полей было десериализованно корректно, а какое было пропущено?
- И могу ли я просто настроить автоматическую десериализацию (без использования `[OnDeserializing]`) так, чтобы пропущенные поля инициализировались конструктором по умолчанию?

Answer (score 3):

Можно посмотреть в сторону формата [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview), который проектировался из расчета на устойчивость к изменениям структуры. Для него есть много реализаций для разных платформ, для .NET могу посоветовать [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю как насчет шарпа, но для Java есть такое решение. Гугловская библиотека [GSon](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) (Google's [JSON](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)) замечательно все это делает. Там можно убавлять/прибавлять поля и все нормально глотается - значения берутся из дефолтного конструктора.

Уверен, что есть порт JSon для C# - там очевидно эта проблема уже решена.

Answer (score 2):

Для этого предназначен интерфейс [`IExtensibleDataObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject%28VS.100%29.aspx). Использовать с `DataContractSerializer`.